# How to create and edit a bitmap

Tags: c++, image, bitmap

I'm trying to create a bitmap that I can change the pixels of and then update the window with that bitmap. I've tried to research a way to just create a bitmap, but that was to no avail.

I need to know how to create a blank bitmap, then change its pixels using x and y coordinates and a color, and then how to draw it to the window. I don't need to save it to the computer and I don't want to convert an existing image into a bitmap.

I'm on windows and using Visual Studio with C++

Just to specify, I need to know the syntax for creating a **blank bitmap with a certain width and height**, and also what function I need to use to change the pixels' colors, and then how to draw a bitmap to the window. Thank you.

Comment: Here's a [starting point](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183377.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

There is a free library **ImgSource** that you can use which has a huge amount of functionality for images.

http://www.smalleranimals.com/isource.htm

It is available in MSDN, but using a library like **ImgSource** may be to your advantage.

It provides simple methods for rendering your image onto a device context. And there is a good support forum.